# AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow at address error?

Tags: c++, clang++

So, I have made a function to reverse a linked list using recursion. My reverse function is working perfectly, but when I try to run asan on my executable, it is giving me a stack-overflow error at a particular address in the reverse function. I have tried everything to fix it. I tried to make all the variables in the stack NULL after their work is done. I have de-allocated all the memory from the heap. I ran valgrind on the file and it tells me all the memory has been freed and there is no leak. What do I do?

[AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHYM0.jpg)

P.S. I am using clang++ compiler in C++.

Comment: What kind of bug?

Comment: What else do you need to help me because I did not allocate large memory on the stack and my recursion definitely ends.  I used gdb to check for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think I got it. ASAN always gives you stack-overflow on deeply recursive functions. There is no bug in the program. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Can you change the code to be tail-recursive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASAN increases your memory requirements since it inserts sentinel values on the stack. So it's possible you aren't hitting the stack limit normally but you are now with ASAN enabled, since each recursive call is now using more stack space than it was before.

The best thing to do in C++ is to not recurse so deeply, but you can also increase your process's stack limits, e.g. in bash:

`ulimit -s unlimited`